# Run node and npm in Windows Server 2008 R2 via SSH

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2008-r2, node.js

I've installed FreeSSH in my Windows Server 2008 R2 and I can SSH with PUTTY, the SSH works fine but I can not run node or npm from the SSH terminal, Error says command not recognized.

Is there some configuration missing?

**EDIT 1**

I cant actually run node and npm specifying the full path or when in nodejs folder, thoughts?

Comment: yes, I can access the server via Team Viewer, I can run the commands from the cmd, but not via SSH

Comment: i can run them from the nodejs installation folder, ideas?

Comment: i don't know, where is it suppose to be, this is windows server 20008 r2

Comment: It's a Windows Server 2008, those commands are for linux

Comment: going over there

Comment: Are they in `PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to make a symbolic link to `node` and `npm`

**Note**: this isn't the cleanest way of doing things, but this will work.

From a Command Prompt run:

`mklink %userprofile%\node.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe"` 
and `mklink %userprofile%\npm.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\npm.exe"`

This will create a **H**ard link to the files `node` and `npm` in your home directory allowing you to just enter `node` or `npm` once you log in through SSH

Comment: i get incorrect syntax error

Comment: D: Still wrong syntax

Comment: I ran the commands separetly and I they worked but still can't run node or npm via SSH

Comment: I might have some insight, when running the command "whoami" from the SSH console I get "win2k8_nodejs/administrator", win2k8_nodejs is the PC name, but there is no user profile named that way, could that be it?

Comment: from the server itself via TeamViwer the command whoami also displays the same user, so I really don't know what's going on